# How to generate random rows with fixed sum of row values?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm developing a question paper generator using C# and SQLite in which I'm supposed to generate random questions from various chapters with total marks of 50. I've tried following SQL query for generating random rows

```
SELECT * FROM Questions
where CourseID=306
  and sem=1
  and (subUnits=1 or subUnits=2)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 20
```

as well as used C# to recursively call this SQL Query until the required total marks are obtained. But doing so takes too much time, and I know it's not the most efficient method out there.

Is there any other method to achieve this result efficiently using only SQL or using it along with C#?

Comment: your table structure and data would help also, if you predetermine how many questions with specific marks would help as well like 18 questions of 2 marks and 1 question of 14 marks would be much easier...

Comment: @TinTran Actually, Users input questions as well as marks. So, the marks cannot be predetermined.

Comment: If the marks are unknown then you won't know if you're able to get total 50 marks..your code might run forever

Comment: @TinTran That's what I was saying. I know there are thousands of 1, 2, 3, 4,5,7,10,15,20 Marks questions. So, practically it won't run forever but takes a considerable amount of time.
I'm expecting something like this...

`SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM Questions
where CourseID=306
  and sem=1
  and (subUnits=1 or subUnits=2)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 20)
WHERE SUM(Marks)=50`

I know that's sort of weird syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: it's probably faster to try to find combinations of 1,2,3,4,5,7,10,15,20 that add up to 50...in code C# (I don't know C#), then once you have the combination and know what you're looking for, you query the db.

Comment: You could sum(mark) in SQL in a stored procedure and loop there.   Of just print them down do C# on in List and do the random there.